# Is there a standard iOS "Push Notifications View" that is reusable?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

What I mean by this is when you have the app in the background/closed and you send a push notification, you will see the normal looking notification pop up at the top of the screen like the following:

[image]

I am trying to mimic that exact view to handle push notifications while in the app.  I've already handled the code that will pick up the notification while in app, and it will display a custom view, using the CWStatusBarNotification pod.

But so far I have been unable to replicate that EXACT look that I am going for.  I'm wondering if there is a standard reusable view that is included with iOS or if someone else made one, where it has outlets I can set for the image and text to make it look just like the above image.  I want the image size and spacing to be identical, as well as the color/opacity of it.

Or if there is not a view that I can use, if anyone knows the measurements/constraints of the push notification (like the height, the image size/offset, text font/size/offset, etc) that would be just as helpful because I could create my own view for it.

Does anyone know if this exists anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure trying to exactly imitate a system UI element is a good idea? Users will expect it to do the same things as said element, which will not necessarily be the case.

Comment: I wouldn't mimic it at all. What happens when the next iOS changes how notifications look and you get to spend an entire day trying to mimic the new one. Create an alert that fits your application.

Comment: @rickster well it is going to do the same thing that the system notification does, it will just go to the text message that the person sent them, same as if the app was closed or in the background.

Comment: @DanielStorm that is a good point though, I will keep that in mind and talk to the others about it.  Also notifications across versions of iOS may look different too, which causes another issue.  Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to schedule a local notification using :

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
notification.alertBody = "Hey you!"
notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["key": "value"]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that local notifications work the same as push notifications, in the sense that they will not display if the app is in the foreground.  I tried this a few days ago and nothing happens when the code is hit, and I'm pretty sure it's due to the way iOS handles notifications in general.